# Can we transform pattern in shape by using handle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, transform

I create a pattern in perspective view , but when I fill my shape by my pattern , I need Move my pattern in my shape .
As I see I can do it by entering position of pixels , the question is Can I move the pattern by using handle ?

---

this is my pattern

[image: this is my pattern]

this is my shape when I fill by my pattern

[image]

I know I should use this panel to move my pattern in my shape

[image]

but I think it is easier to use handle to move it.

Comment: What program is this about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pattern isn't constructed properly. You should *not* be using a transformed area that has an odd shape to set the pattern tile. Your pattern should be a flat, untransformed rectangle.

*Then* you draw your odd shape and fill it with the pattern and transform the pattern.

All that being posted: If you have **Transform Pattern Tiles** checked in the **Preferences**, then **yes** you can transform patterns the same way you would any other shape.

Comment: Do u know  why I have to do this ? because when I create pattern in rectangle  I have to convert it to Mesh then distort it  and converting to Mesh causes some problem ,such as we can't change shape by vertex easily , or we can't change color or ... so it isn't better to create pattern in a perspective view :D ?

Comment: No it is not better to create a pattern in perspective. All patterns should be created flat. You can always edit the pattern after the fact via the pattern editor in Illustrator.

Comment: assume my pattern is flat we can move it by handle ?